# MySql consulta anidada

Tags: mysql

me podrían ayudar a mostrar mas columnas en un select anidado, en la consulta que tengo me muestra "La columna 't.id' en field list es desconocida".
Si le quito el join y el u.name me muestran los datos correctamente, pero yo quiero ver mas columnas.

```
SELECT t.id, u.name

FROM (SELECT t.id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date(date_created), date(cust_33)) AS dias
              
FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t WHERE t.is_active = 1 AND t.date_created BETWEEN '2022-12-01' AND '2022-12-31') AS  resultado

JOIN wpam_psmsc_customers u ON u.id = t.customer

WHERE dias between 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En una subconsulta, tienes que referirte al resultado de la consulta anidada como una tabla derivada y hacer referencias a esa tabla,aquí encontrarás la estructura de como debe realizarse [mysql derived-tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)

en tu caso, asumiendo cierta estructura de tus tablas, la consulta quedaría:

```
SELECT 
  resultado.id,
  u.name 
FROM
  (
    SELECT t.id,t.customer,TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,DATE(date_created),DATE(cust_33)) AS dias 
    FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t WHERE t.is_active = 1 AND t.date_created BETWEEN '2022-12-01' AND '2022-12-31'
  ) AS resultado 
  JOIN wpam_psmsc_customers u ON u.id = resultado.customer 
  WHERE resultado.dias BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estudiare la documentación,, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta